# The head of an unnumbered chapter

Tags: chapters

I have used the package fncychap with the option Glenn for all my numbered chapters and I want to use the same heading for my unnumbered chapters like Introduction, Conclusion and Bibliography without the word Chapter. How can I do that? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! Can you please post the code for a minimal but complete document we can compile as a starting point? This makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Are you using `\chapter*{Introduction}`? The default for `\chapter*` under `\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}` is to remove the `Chapter X` numbering.

Comment: @Werner Thank you for your response, it works very well

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\chapter*{title}` for unnumbered

Comment: Please avoid snippet answers and *always* post compilable examples.

Comment: @Mu30 murugans2katgmail, in fact, \chapter*{title} gives what I'm looking for only with the option Glenn

Comment: @eliza look at the very first comment, you were asked to provide a minimal working example. I am not sure if your issue is solved, you did not accept the answer. You state you are using Glenn and now say that the solution only works for Glenn. What?

Comment: @Johannes_B, thank you my issue is solved, yes I used Glenn and for this latter, if we use the command \chapter*{title} it gives the same heading of other chapters without the word chapter and that's what I was looking for. But for the other options (Lenny, etc) it gives a different result.